# Error installing dlib in windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, cmake, pip, dlib

I can't seem to install dlib on my windows 10 machine using pip.
I am using python 3.6.1
i did try pip installing dlib using the following commands

```
pip install dlib
```

but it returns me with the following error.

```
Collecting dlib
Using cached dlib-19.10.0.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: dlib
Running setup.py install for dlib ... error
Complete output from command c:\users\ayush\appdata\local\programs\python        \python36-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Ayush\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-iu6_cvvs\\dlib\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Ayush\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uhnfkgpd-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
running install
running build
running build_py
package init file 'dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
running build_ext
Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\Ayush\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-iu6_cvvs\dlib\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\Ayush\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-iu6_cvvs\dlib\build\lib.win32-3.6 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\users\ayush\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\Ayush\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-iu6_cvvs\dlib\build\lib.win32-3.6'
-- Building for: NMake Makefiles
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
  The CMAKE_C_COMPILER:

    cl

  is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

  To use the NMake generator with Visual C++, cmake must be run from a shell
  that can use the compiler cl from the command line.  This environment is
  unable to invoke the cl compiler.  To fix this problem, run cmake from the
  Visual Studio Command Prompt (vcvarsall.bat).

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
  the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
  The CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:

    cl

  is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

  To use the NMake generator with Visual C++, cmake must be run from a shell
  that can use the compiler cl from the command line.  This environment is
  unable to invoke the cl compiler.  To fix this problem, run cmake from the
  Visual Studio Command Prompt (vcvarsall.bat).

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path
  to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/Ayush/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-build-iu6_cvvs/dlib/build/temp.win32-3.6/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/Ayush/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-build-iu6_cvvs/dlib/build/temp.win32-3.6/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Ayush\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-iu6_cvvs\dlib\setup.py", line 249, in <module>
    'Topic :: Software Development',
  File "c:\users\ayush\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "c:\users\ayush\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "c:\users\ayush\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "c:\users\ayush\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
    return orig.install.run(self)
  File "c:\users\ayush\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 545, in run
    self.run_command('build')
  File "c:\users\ayush\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "c:\users\ayush\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "c:\users\ayush\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "c:\users\ayush\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "c:\users\ayush\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\Ayush\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-iu6_cvvs\dlib\setup.py", line 129, in run
    self.build_extension(ext)
  File "C:\Users\Ayush\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-iu6_cvvs\dlib\setup.py", line 163, in build_extension
    subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
  File "c:\users\ayush\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 291, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\Ayush\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-iu6_cvvs\\dlib\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\Ayush\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-iu6_cvvs\\dlib\\build\\lib.win32-3.6', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\\users\\ayush\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36-32\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\Ayush\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-iu6_cvvs\\dlib\\build\\lib.win32-3.6']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

i have Cmake installed and i also tried setting a environmental variable path to the Cmake library but the same error occurs.

Comment: Have you tried to execute this under `Visual Studio Command Prompt (vcvarsall.bat)`, as the error message suggests?

Comment: @Tsyvarev No i didn't do i need to install Visual C++ 2015 Build Tools for this??

Comment: For use CMake, you should have at least one **build tool** and **compiler** suitable for it. As CMake uses `NMake Makefiles` generator, you seems to have NMake as *build tool*. What **compiler** do you have?

Comment: Thanks man installing `Visual Studio Command Prompt (vcvarsall.bat)` fixed the problem and the compiler i am using is `Microsoft C/C++ Compiler`